# Symfony2 Ajax Call to Multiple Controllers in one Bundle

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I have a special bundle only for Ajax calls that has two controllers that do two ajax calls. The two controllers have two routes. This is a basic jquery ajax call...

```
            $.ajax(url, {
                accepts: 'application/json',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log(jqXHR.status);
                    if(jqXHR.status == 200) {
                        dataObject = data;
                    }
                });

            return dataObject;
```

Ajax request are sent on two diffrent link. The first one is sent for a project / portfolio gallery, the second one for an image gallery. The first one work, the second one doesn't. Also, there is no status code or anything else that could tell me there's something wronk.

Basicly, the sam code in the project gallery works, but in the image gallery doesn't.

If I try to call the route manualy, through the url, the controller is called and works. The route also works.

What could be the problem here? I've done good debugging and everything checks out except the request being sent for the Symfony controller.

**EDIT:** I forgot to check before, but the request is being sent and the status code is 200. But the controller or route are not executed.

Answer (score 1):

I've been giving the wrong url to ajax. Someone ban for 30 day on Stack Overflow for being an idiot

Comment: Haha :D also have a look at [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)